# Suppose that half of the elements of G have order 2 and the other half form a subgroup H of order n. Prove that H is an abelian subgroup of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $n>1$ be a positive integer. Let $G$ be a group of order $2n$. Suppose that half of the elements of G have order 2 and the other half forma a subgroup $H$ of order $n$. Prove that H is an abelian subgroup of G.

I can only deduce from the index of $H$ that $H$ is normal. I am not sure how to move on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose $x\notin H$. Then the coset $xH$ consists of all of the elements of order $2$. Thus if $h\in H$, then 
$$xhxh=1$$
so
$$xhx=h^{-1}$$
Suppose $a,b\in H$. Then
$$xabx=b^{-1}a^{-1}$$
and this is also equal to
$$(xax)(xbx)=a^{-1}b^{-1}$$
Thus
$$b^{-1}a^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$$
for all $a,b\in H$, which is equivalent to saying that $H$ is abelian.

Comment: How do you get $b^{-1}a^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$?

Comment: @math The middle three equations explain that. Conjugating an element of $H$ by $x$ yields its inverse. Conjugation is a homomorphism.

Comment: yes ! Thank you!