# Maximum number of Sylow subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I've been studying Sylow-$p$ subgroups, and I've come across this problem.

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Show that the number of Sylow subgroups of $G$ is at most $\frac{2}{3}|G|$ . ($|G|$ is the number of elements of $G$).

I am having trouble figuring this one out, I was wondering if anyone could help?

Comment: The bound is for Sylow $p$-subgroups or Sylow subgroups of any kind??!

Comment: Where did you come across the problem?

Comment: Possibly the problem can be traced back one [small] step to [**AoPS**](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1087677s1_maximum_number_of_sylow_subgroups). You may have to ask there to find out its original source.

Comment: About this post, see also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/209023/origin-of-group-theory-problem-bound-on-number-of-sylow-subgroups

Answer (score 12):

Let $G$ be a group and let
$$|G|=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_n^{a_n}$$ 
where $p_1<p_2<\cdots<p_n$ are distinct primes and $a_i\geq 1$ for all $i$. Let $N_p$ denote the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups and let $N$ denote the total number of Sylow subgroups, i.e. the sum of all $N_{p_i}$. By the fact that $N_p\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ and $N_p||G|$ we must have that
$$N_{p_i}\leq \frac{|G|}{p_i^{a_i}}$$

Suppose $p_i\neq 2$ and $a_i=1$. Then $N_{p_i}$ is equal to the number of elements of order $p_i$ divided by $p_i-1$. Thus if $i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_m$ satisfy $a_{i_k}=1$ for all $k$ and these are all the indices for which the exponent is $1$, then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m}{N_{p_{i_k}}}\leq \frac{|G|}{p_{i_1}-1}$$

**New, more elementary proof**

There are five cases.

**(1) $a_i\geq 2$ for all $i$.**

In this case
$$N\leq\sum_{p}{\frac{1}{p^2}|G|}$$
where $p$ ranges over all primes, and the sum of the squares of the recpirocals of all primes is less than or equal to $\frac{453}{1000}$, so
$$N\leq \frac{453}{1000}|G|<\frac{2}{3}|G|$$

**(2) $p_1=2$, $G$ has a normal $2$-complement, and $N_2<\frac{1}{2}|G|$**

Let $H$ be the normal $2$-complement. Then $H$ contains all Sylow subgroups for primes other than $2$. Suppose $H$ is of order $2^{m-a_1}|G|$, where $m<a_1$. By induction on $n$ we have that
$$\sum_{k>1}{N_{p_k}}\leq \frac{2}{3}|H|=\frac{2^{m+1}}{3\cdot 2^{a_1}}|G|\leq\frac{1}{3}|G|$$
Since $N_2<\frac{|G|}{2}$ we have that $N_2\leq \frac{|G|}{4}$, hence
$$N\leq N_2+\frac{1}{3}|G|\leq \frac{1}{4}|G|+\frac{1}{3}|G|=\frac{7}{12}|G|<\frac{2}{3}|G|$$

**(3) $p_1=3$ or $p_2=3$ and $G$ has a normal $3$-complement**

This is similar to the previous case.

Let $H$ be the normal $3$-complement. Then $H$ contains all Sylow subgroups for primes other than $3$. Suppose $H$ is of order $3^{m-a_1}|G|$, where $m<a_1$. By induction on $n$ we have that
$$\sum_{k\neq 2}{N_{p_k}}\leq \frac{2}{3}|H|=\frac{2\cdot 3^{m-a_1}}{3\cdot 3^{a_1}}|G|\leq\frac{2}{9}|G|$$
So
$$N\leq N_3+\frac{2}{9}|G|\leq \frac{1}{3}|G|+\frac{2}{9}|G|=\frac{5}{9}|G|<\frac{2}{3}|G|$$

**(4) $G$ has no normal $3$ complement, and if $p_1=2$ then $G$ also has no normal $2$-complement**

The condition implies that $a_1\geq 2$, unless $p_1\geq 5$. In this case neither the Sylow $2$-subgroup nor the Sylow $3$-subgroup is in the center of its normalizer (unless each respective subgroup is trivial), so by Burnside's transfer theorem we have $N_2\leq\frac{1}{8}|G|$ (which also holds if there is no nontrivial Sylow $2$-subgroup) and $N_3\leq\frac{1}{6}|G|$ (which also holds if there is no nontrivial $3$-subgroup). The contribution of the $N_{p_i}$ for $p_i\geq 5$ such that $a_i=1$ is as usual at most $\frac{1}{4}|G|$. Thus
$$N\leq\sum{\frac{1}{p^2}|G|}-\frac{1}{4}|G|-\frac{1}{9}|G|+\frac{1}{8}|G|+\frac{1}{6}|G|+\frac{1}{4}|G|\leq \frac{2851}{4500}|G|<\frac{2}{3}|G|$$

**(5) $p_1=2$ and $N_2=\frac{1}{2}|G|$**

In this case as below we are in the situation of [Suppose that half of the elements of G have order 2 and the other half form a subgroup H of order n. Prove that H is an abelian subgroup of G.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034456/suppose-that-half-of-the-elements-of-g-have-order-2-and-the-other-half-form-a-su), meaning that we have an abelian subgroup of index $2$, hence every Sylow $p_i$ subgroup for $i>1$ is normal, hence
$$N=\frac{1}{2}|G|+n-1$$
and since in particular $n-1\leq\frac{|G|}{6}$ because $|G|\geq 2\cdot 3^{n-1}$ we have that
$$N\leq \frac{2}{3}|G|$$
This bound is tight, with $S_3$ giving an example of equality (in fact $S_3$ is unique in this sense, which can be seen from the proof).

**Old, overpowered proof (no need to read, preserved for posterity)**

Our proof is broken into six cases (case 4 has some subcases though):

**(1) $a_i\geq 2$ for all $i$**

In this case
$$N\leq\sum_{p}{\frac{1}{p^2}|G|}$$
where $p$ ranges over all primes, and the sum of the squares of the recpirocals of all primes is less than or equal to $\frac{23}{50}$, so
$$N\leq \frac{23}{50}|G|<\frac{2}{3}|G|$$

**(2) $a_i=1$ for some $i$ and either $p_1\neq 2$ or $p_1=2$ and $a_1\geq 4$**

For $p$ prime we have 
$$\sum_{p>3}{\frac{1}{p^2}}\leq \frac{23}{50}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{9}=\frac{89}{900}$$
If $p_1\geq 3$ we have
$$N\leq \sum_{k=1}^{m}{N_{p_{i_k}}}+\frac{89}{900}|G|\leq\frac{1}{p_1-1}|G|+\frac{89}{900}|G|\leq \frac{1}{2}|G|+\frac{89}{900}|G|=\frac{539}{900}|G|<\frac{2}{3}|G|$$
If $p_1=2$ we have assumed $a_1\geq 4$. If $p_2>3$, or $p_2=3$ and $a_2=1$ then since
$$\frac{1}{16}+\sum_{p>3}{\frac{1}{p^2}}\leq \frac{23}{50}-\frac{1}{9}-\frac{3}{16}=\frac{581}{3600}$$
we have
$$N\leq \sum_{k=1}^{m}{N_{p_{i_k}}}+\frac{581}{3600}|G|\leq \frac{1}{p_2-1}|G|+\frac{581}{3600}|G|\leq\frac{2381}{3600}|G|<\frac{2}{3}$$
If $p_2=3$ and $a_2>1$, let $p_k$ be the smallest integer such that $a_k=1$. Then since
$$\frac{1}{16}+\sum_{p\geq 3}{\frac{1}{p^2}}\leq \frac{23}{50}-\frac{3}{16}=\frac{109}{400}$$
we have
$$N\leq \sum_{k=1}^{m}{N_{p_{i_k}}}+\frac{109}{400}|G|\leq \frac{1}{p_k-1}|G|+\frac{109}{400}|G|\leq\frac{209}{400}|G|<\frac{2}{3}$$

**(3) $p_1=2$, $G$ has a normal $2$-complement and $N_2<\frac{|G|}{2}$**

Let $H$ be the normal $2$-complement. Then $H$ contains all Sylow subgroups for primes other than $2$. Suppose $H$ is of order $2^{m-a_1}|G|$, where $m<a_1$. By induction on $n$ we have that
$$\sum_{k\neq 2}{N_{p_k}}\leq \frac{2}{3}|H|=\frac{2^{m+1}}{3\cdot 2^{a_1}}|G|\leq\frac{1}{3}|G|$$
Since $N_2<\frac{|G|}{2}$ we have that $N_2\leq \frac{|G|}{4}$, hence
$$N\leq N_2+\frac{1}{3}|G|\leq \frac{1}{4}|G|+\frac{1}{3}|G|=\frac{7}{12}|G|<\frac{2}{3}|G|$$

**(4) $p_1=2$, $a_1\leq 3$, the Sylow $2$-subgroups are abelian but not cyclic, and $G$ does not have a normal $2$-complement**

[The Walter theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_theorem) states that if $O(G)$ is the maximal normal subgroup of odd order, then $G/O(G)$ is a direct product of $2$-groups, projective special linear groups, Janko groups, and Ree groups of type ${}^2G_2$. Let $H$ be a Sylow $2$-subgroup. Then the number of distinct conjugates of $HO(G)$ is the same as the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups of $G/O(G)$. Call this number $N_2(G/O(G))$ and let $N_2(HO(G))$ denote the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups of  $HO(G)$. Then
$$N_2\leq N_2(G/O(G))N_2(HO(G))$$
We split into cases:

**(4a) The Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G/O(G)$ is normal and $[G:HO(G)]>3$**

In this case $HO(G)$ contains all Sylow $2$-subgroups. If $HO(G)$ is of index larger than $3$ then $N_2\leq \frac{|G|}{16}$ and we may argue as in case (2).

**(4b) The Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G/O(G)$ is normal and $[G:HO(G)]=3$**

If $HO(G)$ is of index $3$, then $HO(G)$ contains all Sylow subgroups except for the $3$-subgroups. Let $k$ be the smallest prime such that $p_k$ has an exponent of $1$ in the prime factorization of $|HO(G)|$. We can argue as in (2) to obtain that
$$\sum_{p_i\neq 3}{N_{p_i}}=N(HO(G))\leq\frac{23}{50}(|G|/3)+\frac{1}{p_k-1}(|G|/3)<\frac{1}{3}|G|$$
and since $N_{3}\leq \frac{1}{3}|G|$ we have that $N\leq\frac{2}{3}|G|$.

**(4c) $G/O(G)$ has a simple projective special linear group as a normal subgroup**

In this case the normal subgroup of odd index given by Walter's theorem is either $PSL_2(2^m)$ with $m>1$, $PSL_2(q)$ where $q\equiv \pm 3\pmod{8}$, or either of these groups with an extra $\mathbb{Z}_2$ factor (this follows from the constraint $a_1\leq 3$). By [Sylow 2-subgroups of the group $\mathrm{PSL}(2,q)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170329/sylow-2-subgroups-of-the-group-mathrmpsl2-q), $N_2(G/O(G))\leq\frac{1}{12}|G/O(G)|$. If $p_2>3$ or $p_2=3$ and $a_2\geq 2$, then we may argue as in case (2).

If $p_2=3$ and $a_2=1$, we can squeeze out the result by noting that $|O(G)|$ is not divisible by $3$, hence if $H'$ is a Sylow $3$-subgroup then
$$N_3\leq N_3(G/O(G))N_3(H'O(G))$$
with the notation having the obvious meaning, hence since the normalizer of the $3$-subgroup has order at least $6$ we have
$$\frac{N_3}{|G|}\leq\frac{N_3(G/O(G))}{|G/O(G)|}\leq \frac{1}{6}$$
so
$$N\leq\sum_{p>5}{\frac{1}{p^2}}|G|+N_2+N_3+\sum_{p_i\geq 5}{N_{p_i}}\leq\frac{23}{50}|G|-\frac{1}{4}|G|-\frac{1}{9}|G|-\frac{1}{25}|G|+\frac{1}{12}|G|+\frac{1}{4}|G|+\frac{1}{6}|G|=\frac{503}{900}|G|<\frac{2}{3}|G|$$

**(4d) $G/O(G)$ has a Janko group $J_1$ as a normal subgroup**

In this case the normalizer of a Sylow $2$-subgroup has index $1045$, so $N_2\leq\frac{1}{1045}|G|$, which is more than small enough to apply the argument in case (2).

**(4e) $G/O(G)$ has a Ree group as a normal subgroup**

I couldn't find a reference on the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups of Ree groups, but note that we can deduce that $N_2\leq \frac{|G|}{24}$ because the Sylow $2$-subgroup is of order $8$ and by Burnside's transfer theorem its normalizer must have an additional factor of at least $3$, and this is enough to apply the argument in case (2).

**(5) $p_1=2$, $a_2=3$ and $G$ does not have a normal $2$-complement**

By the Frobenius normal $p$-complement theorem we must have that $|N_G(H)|\geq 16$ where $H$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup, hence $N_2\leq\frac{1}{16}|G|$ and we may argue as in case (2).

**(6) $p_1=2$, $a_1=1$ and $N_2=\frac{|G|}{2}$**

In this case we are in the situation of [Suppose that half of the elements of G have order 2 and the other half form a subgroup H of order n. Prove that H is an abelian subgroup of G.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034456/suppose-that-half-of-the-elements-of-g-have-order-2-and-the-other-half-form-a-su), meaning that we have an abelian subgroup of index $2$, hence every Sylow $p_i$ subgroup for $i>1$ is normal, hence
$$N=\frac{1}{2}|G|+n-1$$
and since in particular $n-1\leq\frac{|G|}{6}$ because $|G|\geq 2\cdot 3^{n-1}$ we have that
$$N\leq \frac{2}{3}|G|$$
This bound is tight, with $S_3$ giving an example of equality (in fact $S_3$ is unique in this sense, which can be seen from the proof).

Comment: +1 for a nice answer. Something I want to make you aware of. After ten edits a system flag on a post is triggered so that moderators can investigate. It used to be a rule that edit #10 automatically turned a question into a community wiki. The reason was that posters used edits to gain more than their fair share of front page air time. It seems clear to me that you had no such goals, so no harm done here. In the future, if you foresee a need for several edits you may want to consider using [the sandbox](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4666/11619). Particularly when fine-tuning LaTeX:-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks for the heads up. The last edit of course was necessary as I had been misled by a mathoverflow post into thinking that simply having a prime dividing the order of a group without its square dividing the order means there is a normal complement. I didn't realize I had hit 10 edits though, that sure is a lot.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I found yet another error in the proof :/ Will it be a problem for me to edit it again when I fix it?

Comment: Of course, not.

Comment: Seeing the length of this answer (didn't really read it through yet), I am really wondering where the OP came across the problem.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft They've been strangely silent about that. I've had a good time with it though.

Comment: @Matt, +1 from me, great answer, still have to digest your proof. I agree with Tobias about the origin of the problem.

Comment: Some cases seem to be missing. One is $p_1=3$, no 3-complement. Another is when there are no 2 and 3- complement and $a_1,a_2\ge 2$. (Also it would be helpful to entitle (4) as "$G$ has no normal 2-complement and no normal 3-complement", and to derive $(p_1,p_2)=(2,3)$, $a_1\ge 2$ as immediate consequences.)

Comment: @YCor $p_1=3$ with no normal 3-complement was meant to be covered by case 4. I thought I edited it to reflect that, let me fix it.

Comment: Prof. @MattSamuel: I have some questions on the "more elementary" solution you gave. Hope you get a chance to answer 'em one of these days: a) What's the definition of normal $p$-complement that you are working with? According to what we find in Wikipedia, the order of a normal $p$-complement in a finite group is coprime to $p$: nevertheless, in (2) you assume that the order of $H$, a normal $2$-complement of $G$, is divisible by $2^{m}$. (b) In the same paragraph, you speak of a proof "by induction on $n$". Could you please add more details to this part of your post? TO BE CONTINUED...

Comment: @absalon you misread. The power of $2$ there is negative. $H$ has odd order.

Comment: (c) Would you be so kind as to suggest a text wherein one can learn of the Burnside transfer theorem which you refer to in (3)? (d) In (5), why is it that every  Sylow $2$-subgroup contributes exactly one involution to $G$? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Prof. @MattSamuel: But the order of G is $2^{a_1} \cdots p_{n}^{a_{n}}$. Hence, $2^{m-a_{1}}$ times $|G|$ is a multiple of $2^{m}$.

Comment: @abs I haven't looked at this in a year. At least that wouldn't be wrong then, just superfluous. We'd have $m=0$. The transfer theorem is a well known result, but I learned this stuff just to write the answer and I've already forgotten it.

Comment: Doesn't it affect the argument "by induction on $n$" that comes immediately afterwards? By the way, what's the exact claim that you are aiming to establish by induction there?

Comment: @absalon it's induction on the number of distinct primes dividing the order, which you can see on the second line of the answer.

Comment: An additional observation: (e) You use $m$ to denote two seemingly unrelated things: on the one hand, it is the number of primes that divide $|G|$ and whose exponent in the canonical factorization of $|G|$ is $1$; on the other hand, it is the exponent to which the prime $2$ appears in the canonical factorization of $|H|$...

Comment: @absalon I don't intend to modify this answer, so if the proof is correct but poorly written it will stay that way. If you find an actual error, I'll delete the answer, but you don't seem to have found one yet.

Comment: Prof. @MattSamuel: Yes, I understand that the induction is on the number of prime factors of the group. The question is: what's the assertion that in (2) you are trying to establish "by induction on $n$"?

Comment: @absalon that the number of Sylow subgroups is less than or equal to two thirds the order.

Comment: Prof. @MattSamuel: I didn't mean to upset you. It's just that I'm trying to understand your solution thru and thru. I understand what you did in (1), and modulo the things I asked above, I believe that I also get what you did in (5). I'm having a difficult time trying to unravel the parts (2)-(4): the good news is that if I manage to see through the argument in (2), my study of your post might be more than half done.

Comment: @absalon I'm not upset, I just erroneously detected some hostility in your rhetoric. It's hard to tell in text!

Comment: Prof. @MattSamuel: On your previous comment: if that is what you are trying to prove in (2), then you DO NEED that the order of $H$ is divisible by $2$, right? Then, the observation I made above on $m$ wouldn't be that superfluous, would it?

Comment: I have to get off-line now. I appreciate that you are taking the time to reply to these messages of mine... TO BE CONTINUED.

Comment: (2) doesn't involve $H$. Where $H$ is used it's actually important that its order is not divisible by $2$.

Comment: Prof. @MattSamuel: In the third case of the more elementary proof, there is a glitch in the restriction imposed on the index of summation, right?

Comment: @absalon I suppose it should say $p_k\neq 3$.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly a partial answer - we first consider a particular prime and then we prove something slightly stronger.

Let $p$ be a prime dividing the order of the group $G$. Now it is standard that $n_p:=|Syl_p(G)|=[G:N_G(P)]$. But $P \subseteq N_G(P)$ and certainly $|P| \geq p$, implying $|N_G(P)| \geq p$. Hence $n_p \leq \frac{1}{p}|G| \leq \frac{1}{2}|G|$.

**Corollary** Let $|G|=p^aq^b$, with $p$ and $q$ prime numbers and $p \lt q$ and $a$ and $b$ positive integers.
(1) If $p=2$ and $q \geq 7$, then the total number of Sylow subgroups of $G$ is smaller than $\frac{2}{3}|G|$.
 
(2) If $p$ is *odd*, then then the total number of Sylow subgroups of $G$ is smaller than $\frac{2}{3}|G|$.

**Proof** Apparently, the total number of Sylow subgroups of $G$ equals $n_p + n_q \leq (\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q})|G|$. In case (1) we have $(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{q})|G| \lt \frac{2}{3}|G|$, since $q \gt 6$. In case (2) $(\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q})|G| \leq (\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5})|G| \lt \frac{2}{3}|G|. \square$

Note: this principle can be further generalized to more prime factors, for example if $|G|=p^aq^br^c$, with $5 \leq p \lt q \lt r$, the bound of $\frac{2}{3}|G|$ still holds.

Comment: I assumed it meant the sum over the primes $p$ dividing the order of $G$ of the number of $p$-Sylow subgroups.

Comment: I agree with the interpretation of @TobiasKildetoft. Looking at $S_{3}$, we see the factor $2/3$ coming out.

Comment: @Andreas, Tobias Could be but it is not clear from the post. Let's try to prove it for all $p$ dividing $|G|$ then. Or come up with a counterexample.

Comment: However, if my interpretation is correct, the obvious attempt $\text{total number of Sylow subgroups} \le \lvert G \rvert \cdot (1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + \dots)$ fails, as the series diverges.

Comment: I don't know how to solve the problem, but I cannot any  possible ambiguity in the question itself - it refers to all Sylow subgroups.

Comment: @DerekHolt Well, with the small caveat that we only count Sylows for those primes dividing the group (i.e. we do not count the trivial subgroup), or the result would fail.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ah yes, I didn't think of that. So, counting the trivial group,  $S_3$  has $5$ Sylow subgroups, and the result is wrong!

Comment: I wonder if there is a (simple) number-theoretic argument, since it concerns particular divisors $n_p$ of the number $|G|$ that are also $\equiv 1$ mod $p$.

Comment: @NickyHekster I have a feeling that might not be sufficient (I think it would be rare for a group to have all its numbers of Sylows be as large as possible in this sense).

Comment: It would be useful to know the source and context of the problem, because that would probably give some indication of the intended solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a strongly simplified proof when the bound $2/3$ is replaced with 1 (using the same starting point as in Matt's answer).

Write $|G|=\prod_p p^{a_p}$. Write $\mathcal{P}$ for the set of primes, $\mathcal{P}_2=\{p\in \mathcal{P}:a_p\ge 2\}$ and $\mathcal{P}_2=\{p\in \mathcal{P}:a_p=1\}$ and $q=\min(p_1)$. Then the number of (nontrivial) Sylow subgroups satisfies:
$$N/|G|\le \sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}_2}\frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}{q}$$
(where $q=\infty$, $1/q=0$ if $\mathcal{P}_1=\emptyset$).

In particular, it satisfies 
$$N/|G|\le \sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}{(q-1)}-\frac{1}{q^2}$$
(see [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53443/sum-of-the-reciprocal-of-the-primes-squared) about $\sum p^{-2}$)

using that $\sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\frac{1}{p^2}\le 453/1000$, we see that if $q\ge 5$ then $N/|G|<453/100+1/4-1/25=663/1000<2/3$.

For $q=3$ it yields $N/|G|<46/100+1/2-1/9<85/100<1$.

For $q=2$ it only yields $N/|G|<46/100+1-1/4=121/100$, so to prove $N<|G|$ we need a little more. If $q=2$, then the signature gives a homomorphism onto the group on 2 elements, and all $p$-Sylow for odd $p$ are contained in the index 2 kernel. If $s_p$ is the set of elements of order $p$ and $N_p$ is the number of $p$-Sylow, we always have

$$\frac{N}{|G|}\le \sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}_2}\frac{N_p}{|G|}+\sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}_1}\frac{s_p}{|G|(p-1)}$$

if $q=2$ we thus have $\frac{N_p}{|G|}\le\frac{1}{2p^2}$ for all $p>2$, also the unique subgroup of index 2 consists exactly of those elements with odd order. So $s_2\le |G|/2$ and $\sum_{p>2}s_p\le |G|/2$, so $\sum_{p>2}s_p/(p-1)\le |G|/4$. Hence

$$\frac{N}{|G|}\le \frac12\left(\sum_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\frac{1}{p^2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\frac{3}{4}<86/100.$$
(Discussing on whether $a_3=1$ improves this to $<80/100$.)

To conclude, using nothing else than Sylow theorem, signature in the symmetric group, and an upper bound for $\sum p^{-2}$, we get $N<(86/100)|G|$.

Answer (score 2):

I record this in case it helps anyone to produce a simpler proof. I interpret "Sylow subgroup" to mean "Non-identity Sylow subgroup". If possible, choose a finite group of minimal order subject to having strictly more than $\frac{2|G|}{3}$ Sylow subgroups. I claim that there is no prime divisor $p$ of $|G|$ such that $G$ has a normal $p$-complement. Suppose otherwise, and let $G = PN$ where $N \lhd G$ has order prime to $p$ and $ 1 \neq P \in {\rm Syl}_{p}(G)$.

Then (using minimality) $G$ has at most $\frac{2|N|}{3}$ Sylow subgroups other than Sylow $p$-subgroups, and $G$ has at most $\frac{|G|}{|P|}$ Sylow $p$-subgroups. Hence $G$ has at most $\frac{|G|}{|P|}\left( \frac{2}{3} +1\right)$ Sylow subgroups.

Hence $\frac{5}{3} \frac{|G|}{|P|} > \frac{2|G|}{3},$ so $|P| < \frac{5}{2}$ and $|P| = 2.$ Let us examine the case $|P| = 2$ more carefully

If $N_{G}(P) = P$, then $G$ has an Abelian subgroup $N$ of odd order and index $2$. It is then clear that $G$ has at most $|N| + \log_{3}(|N|)$ Sylow subgroups. This is at most $\frac{4|N|}{3}$ by elementary calculus since $|N| \geq 3.$ This contradicts the fact that $G$ has more than $\frac{2|G|}{3}$ Sylow subgroups. Hence $N_{G}(P) \neq P$, so $|N_{G}(P)| \geq 3|P|.$

Hence $G$ has at most $\frac{2|G|}{6} + \frac{|G|}{6}$ Sylow subgroups ( using minimality again for the odd Sylow subgroups), so at most $\frac{|G|}{2}$ Sylow subgroups, a contradiction.

Comment: If we exclude the cases when $G$ has a abelien subgroup of index 2 and odd order $\le 35$ (and 2-Sylow acting by $\pm$), it seems it also works with $5/9$ instead of $2/3$.  In view of Matt's proof it would imply that these exceptions put away, we have $N<(5327/9000)|G|$ (so $N<(3/5)|G|)$). But I haven't checked very carefully.